# Using geopackage trigger in QField

Tags: geopackage, qfield, trigger

I tried to create trigger in GeoPackage so one layer would get updated by data from the other, both in the same GeoPackage. It worked perfectly within desktop QGIS but I get this error message in QField:

[image: Qfield error]

Trigger I added to layer 1:

```
CREATE TRIGGER "insert_trigger" AFTER       
INSERT 
ON "layer1" 
BEGIN 
UPDATE "layer1" SET "grid" = (select "col1"     
from  "layer2" where
st_intersects(new."geom","geom")) WHERE
new."fid" == "fid"; 
END
```

I used QField sync plugin to package project using "copy" layer configuration.
When using "offline editing" configuration i get no errors, fields are updated on sync as expected.

Trigger should be ok since it works in desktop. GeoPackage is "mini database" with triggers in it by default that do work in QField so trigger support shouldn't be a problem. What else could be wrong.

Comment: The author has written into a later deleted answer "Not sure what the problem was, most likely somehow corrupt geopackage.".